# HTML <select> giving empty option values

Tags: php, html, mysql

```html
<select>
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('employees'); 



$query = "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(from_date,4) AS date FROM salaries";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 
 $date = $row['date'];
 
 
 echo '<option value="<?php echo $date ?>"><?php echo $date ?></option>';
 
 echo $date;
 
}

mysql_close(); 
?>
</select>
```

When I'm using  tag select options are getting empty values (nothing displays). When I'm deleting select and /select all values are appearing on the screen. Why is that happening and what's wrong with  my code? I wish to display every date as an option.

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're putting php tags within php

```
echo '<option value="<?php echo $date ?>"><?php echo $date ?></option>';
```

should probably be

```
echo '<option value="'.$date.'">'.$date.'</option>';
```

mysql is also deprecated, consider updating

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your coding style preference, you can avoid using concatenation by wrapping your echo'ed string in double quotes.  This will allow you to place variables directly in the string.  The performance benefit is rather microscopic, but you may find it easier to read and debug your work.  I find that it is easy to have an extra or missing single quote and overlook it if there are a bunch of concatenations just to echo variables --  so generally try to avoid it unless writing an inline condition statement or function.

You also don't need to declare a new variable to store `$date = $row['date'];`, it is perfectly valid to echo an array element like this: `$row['date']`.

Use curly brackets around your echo'ed array element.  Notepad++ or whatever you are coding on should (or probably can) nicely color your script to help you identify variables in your string.

[image]

I would update your `mysql_` functions to `mysqli` and write your code this way:

```
if(!$db=new mysqli("localhost","root","","employees")){
    echo "Connection Error: ",$db->connect_error;  // do not echo when live
}elseif(!$result=$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(from_date,4) AS date FROM salaries")){
    echo "Query Syntax Error: ",$db->error;  // do not echo when live
}elseif(!$result->num_rows){
    echo "Query Logic Error: No dates found in salaries table";  // write your preferred message
}else{
    echo "<select>";
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value=\"{$row['date']}\">{$row['date']}</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

*Notice that any double quotes used inside of the double quoted echo line must be escaped/prepended with `\`.

In the comments under the PHP manual specs @ http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php there are some discussion points about string concatenation, curly brackets, and performance speed.